# How GZIPInputStream works

Tags: java, file, ftp, transfer

I need clear picture of how GZIPInputstream works. I created the object of FileInputStream and passed it to GZIPInputstream to read the my config.tar.gz file. How things will happen now.
If i want to transfer this file using ftp , say using com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient,  from one m/c to another in compressed form , then why i am getting the transferred file size of same size as that of original file before compression.

Comment: Please show the client code.

Answer (score 1):

You are decompressing the file by using GZIPInputStream as this is what it does.  If you want to read the compressed data, just use FileInputStream and it will be read unaltered.